# After erasing the external hard drive it becomes 800GB instead of 3TB

Tags: hard-drive

[image]

This appears to be a quirk that happens randomly with macOS. Usually I would format the external disk again with a Windows PC but currently I do not have one. How would you reclaim the missing disk? (APPLE HD D ST3000DM001 Media has 3TB and after erasing the content, it becomes 800GB)

Comment: You have the drive in a shell that can only handle drives unto 2.2 TB in size. In your case, the result is 3 TB - 2.2 TB = 800 GB.

Comment: Interesting, how did it work as a 3TB drive previously?

Comment: You mentioned Windows.  Are you *intending* to format it APFS?

Comment: @Allan I am open to format it to exFAT

Comment: I think @DavidAnderson might be onto something. The USB adapter I used for this drive might not support 3TB to begin with. It requires a special driver on Windows to format it to full 3TB. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ChbFu8jbAR4

Comment: That doesn’t make sense.  More than 2TB was a [problem back in Win Vista/7 days](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/backup-and-storage/support-for-hard-disks-exceeding-2-tb).

Comment: aeroxy: In video you have linked to, the Computer Management program has correctly identified the drive being 3 TB in size. (Where Microsoft uses GB, when they really mean GiB. In other words, 2794.52 GiB = 3000.59 GB.) The image you posted incorrectly shows your drive to be 801.57 GB in size. Therefore, I believe the issues addressed in the video are unrelated to your question.

Comment: @DavidAnderson it is related. I have fixed it using a friend's windows.

Comment: So basically you have an USB adaptor that is Windows compatible, but not Mac compatible. (By Mac compatible, I mean compatible with macOS.) Do you still have a question to be answered?

Comment: @DavidAnderson it's not windows compatible either. It requires a specific software. The same software does not have a mac version. I am looking for someone to provide one.

Comment: You say you *"have fix it using a friend's windows"*. Ok, prove this to me. Edit your question and add a new image where the size has changed from 801.57 GB to 3 TB.